# Advantage of using JWT token or/and Session in Single Page Application?

Tags: laravel, session, jwt, single-page-application

In 2020, is there any advantages of using JWT token at all in SPA ?

All the stuff that jwt can do, Session can do it all, or session can do it even better than JWT.

Can I just use Session-cookie mechanism for my SPA instead of using jwt token?

Jwt token itself needs to be stored in a http only cookie, jwt token functions exactly like session in Laravel.

What are other things that Jwt do better than session cookies?